# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_all_security_groups'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I am kinda stuck here.

```
    .
regions = ['us-west-2','eu-central-1','ap-southeast-1']  ##Prod VPC
data = []
header = ["Port","Open For","Security group","Instance Details"]

for region in regions:
    connection=ec2.connect_to_region(region)
    print connection
    sg=connection.get_all_security_groups()
    print sg
    try:
        for securityGroup in sg:
           for rule in securityGroup.rules:
               if '0.0.0.0/0' in str(rule.grants):
                  for instanceid in securityGroup.instances():
                      instanceId=str(instanceid)
                     # print instanceId
                      tag = getTag(connection, instanceId.split(':')[1])
                      if tag is not None:
                        # print tab              
                         tab =[str(rule.to_port),"0.0.0.0/0",str(securityGroup.name),str(getTag(connection, instanceId.split(':')[1]))]
                         data.append(tab)
    except Exception,e:
        pass
```

This results in the following

```
    EC2Connection:ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
    [SecurityGroup: too many sec groups here.........]
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aws_sec_scan.py", line 29, in <module>
    sg=connection.get_all_security_groups()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_all_security_groups'
```

why am i getting that "None"?

Comment: What is `ec2.connect_to_region(region)` returning?

Comment: Your connection is None. It is obvious from the logs.

Comment: It seems that you have the `Connection` in the first iteration of loop but you lost it in the second iteration.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com

Comment: @Nishant Please check the my answer, you get the above value only in the first iteration and not in the second one.

Comment: Are you sure? It looks like at some moment that connection becomes `None`. This is very likely the source of your problem.

Comment: yes.. and thats whats bugging me.,. and i think i noticed that this runs fine from some other machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking up the stacktrace:

In the *first iteration*, you have the `connection`, hence there is no error:

```
EC2Connection:ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com # this is your connection
[SecurityGroup: too many sec groups here.........] # this being the security groups
```

In the *second iteration*:

```
None # this prints the connection you obtained for that 'region'
```

So now if you use `sg=connection.get_all_security_groups()` you get following error since the `connection` is `None`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aws_sec_scan.py", line 29, in <module>
    sg=connection.get_all_security_groups()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_all_security_groups'
```

Comment: okay,, i have updated the code , i am unsure how to NOT break the connection here

Comment: Does it makes sense ? why the connection is "None" ? I can't figure out

Comment: It doesn't make sense but could you just try `ec2.connect_to_region(region)` in the console for the particular region where you are getting None.

Comment: `>>> from boto import ec2
>>> ec2.connect_to_region("us-west-1")
EC2Connection:ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: I meant try it for different regions and check if you are getting the connection for each of those or only for some of those and if you always get None for some particular regions etc.

Comment: oh yeah i think i got an error , 

>>> ec2.connect_to_region("eu-central-1")
>>> print ec2.connect_to_region("eu-central-1")
None
` THIS IS THE PROBLEM., but why??? the region exists and the there is no typo

Comment: I am not sure I will be able help beyond this point. Now that you have the cause you can google and check if others have faced this problem.

Comment: thanks mate. i just discovered that the same set of commands run perfectly from my Local VM and this is only for the AWS machine...Gonna see what i find

Answer (score 0):

This is because connection is None and you are trying to call a function from None value

```
sg=connection.get_all_security_groups()
```

So check for issues in getting the connection right.

Comment: Does it makes sense ? why the connection is "None" ? I can't figure out